# Download a file from an FTP using Curl with PHP

Tags: php, curl, ftp, libcurl

I'm trying to download a file from an FTP server using Curl.  I can paste the URL into my browser and it downloads fine.  The problem is that with Curl and PHP, I believe the FTP server is doing a redirect and Curl won't follow.  I get the error message, "Server denied you to change to the given directory".

EDIT:  I had %2f in the code and deleted it.  That was from a prior test.

My code is:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$file = fopen("temp.zip", 'w');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://idx.living.net/idx_fl_ftp_down/idx_naples_dn/naples_data.zip");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_SSL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");
curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_error($curl);
```

Any way to force Curl to behave the way the browser does when downloading the file?

Comment: Never heard that FTP servers can do a redirect, that's normally a feature of the HTTP protocol, not FTP protocol.

Comment: I don't think the FTP protocol has a redirect response, like HTTP. This is probably not your problem. Try eavesdropping on the ftp connection with wireshark to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Is the `/%2fidx_fl_ftp_down/` part of the path valid?  Should it not be just `/idx_fl_ftp_down/`?  `%2f` is the url encoding of `/`.  I think it may be trying to change into and invalid/non-existent directory.

Comment: I think the problem is that Curl is logging into the FTP server at simply idx.living.net and THEN trying to change directory.  That won't work in my FTP program either.  It just needs to download the file in one step like the browser does and I don't know how to force that.

Comment: This may help: https://technicalsanctuary.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/curl-curl-9-server-denied-you-to-change-to-the-given-directory/

Answer (score 0):

I know this dont answer your question the way it should be ( using curl ).
But here's a non curl code to download a file on a ftp server with php.

```
$local_file = 'output.rar';
$server_file = '/somedir/1/bar/foo/somearchive.rar';
$ftp_user_name='some_login';
$ftp_user_pass='Password';
$ftp_server='HOST';
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

/* uncomment if you need to change directories
if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, "<directory>")) {
    echo "Current directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
} else { 
    echo "Couldn't change directory\n";
}
*/

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Notes:

1. ftp_ssl_connect() is not intended for use with sFTP. To use sFTP with PHP, please see ssh2_sftp().
2. The FTP server address parameter shouldn't have any trailing slashes and shouldn't be prefixed with ftp://.