# Download file from FTP using curl in php

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I'm making a php script, intended to run in CLI, wich will help me to download files on a ftp server.
I'm going to show you exactly what's wrong, but before i'll explain you what's the context.

I'm registred on a website that share oldies games image file. When we want to download a file on this site, we have to be logued to retrieve the download link. Then, the link given is an FTP download link.

I made a capture of the FTP connection packets using Wireshark, too compare it with my scripted FTP transfert that fails.

So,..
The FTP server accept anonymous connection.
When i download a file using my browser, the link for the file is something like that;

**ftp://website.url/somefolder/1/foo/bar/SOMEOLDIE.rar**

Now, if i connect to this FTP using FileZilla, with anonymous login i get acces, i see some folders, but when i go to "somefolder" where my iso have to be, the folder is empty.

Look at this image, then i'll show you the code.
[image]
Now the code;

```
function download_file($url){
    echo "Downloading: ".$url;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $fp = fopen("data/output.rar", "w");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'data/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "anonymous:mozilla@example.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_exec($ch);
    //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
    //echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Can anyone help me with that ? I'm not familiar with curl, and i dont know how to tell curl to send exactly the commands i want.

Thank you !

EDIT: look at this, its exactly the same problem; [Need help downloading a file using PHP and Curl from an FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373522/need-help-downloading-a-file-using-php-and-curl-from-an-ftp?rq=1)

Comment: What's wrong with using the ftp_* functions? (Ignoring that generally FTP should be steered away from).

Comment: Thanks to point me in that direction, i forgoted to check PHP ftp's capability,..
I tried something like `file_put_contents("out.rar", file_get_contents($url, false, $context)); ` with no success, i'll try ftp_* funcs now !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok guys i get it :)

I used the ftp_* functions for ftp, in place of curl, because curl tried to change directories, but its not allowed on this ftp server, so the code i used is;

```
$local_file = 'output.rar';
$server_file = '/somedir/1/bar/foo/somearchive.rar';
$ftp_user_name='anonymous';
$ftp_user_pass='mozilla@example.com';
$ftp_server='server.host';
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

/* uncomment if you need to change directories
if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, "<directory>")) {
    echo "Current directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
} else { 
    echo "Couldn't change directory\n";
}
*/

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

It works !!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to feed CURLOPT_URL the full URL to the file. Also if you want to download a file you might want to save it somewhere.

Working example:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$file = fopen("ls-lR.gz", 'w');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://ftp.sunet.se/ls-lR.gz"); #input
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); #output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$_FTP[username]:$_FTP[password]");
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried, but i get the same output in Wireshark..
And i used exactly the same code you gived to me ..

Comment: Nope, but i was using full path to archive when i made my first try, now with your example, i just has to change some things, re-order directives for curlopt, and deleted some others, but no success